# Hibernate Criteria Enum

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, criteria

if you have a Enum in your entities like this:

```
@Entity
public class AA{
    @Embedded
    public BB b;
...
}

@Embeddable
public class BB{
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(50)")
    private CC c;
    ...
}

public enum CC{
    D("DDD","123"),
    E("EEE","456");
}
```

then use hibernate criteria query like this:

```
Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(AA.class);
List<AA> list = crit.add(Restrictions.eq("b.c", CC.D)).list();
```

Comment: What you want to know is not clear from your question ?

Comment: I have no questions now,just want to show others who may encounter this problem

Comment: What is your question??

Comment: You have the answer for my question

Answer (score 1):

You need to create alias for the embedded objects then access it properities via alias name.

Do like this

```
Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(AA.class,"a");
crit.createAlias("a.b", "b");
List<AA> list = crit.add(Restrictions.eq("b.c", CC.D)).list();
```

Comment: I have not create alias,but it run correctly，could you tell me why?